# unknown property error when using standard controller contact

Tags: apex

```
<apex:page standardController="contact" extensions="testemail">
<apex:form>
<apex:commandButton value="SendEmail" accesskey="{!sendemail}"/>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

class

```
public class testemail{
    private final list<id> contactids;
    public list<contact>con;
    public testemail(Apexpages.StandardController Controller)
    {
        con = [select id from contact limit 250];
        for (integer i=0;i<250;i++)
        {
            contactids.add(con[i].id);
        }
    }
    public void sendemail()
    {
        Messaging.MassEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.MassEmailMessage();
        mail.setTargetObjectIds(contactids);
        Messaging.SendEmail(new Messaging.MassEmailMessage[]{mail});
    }
}
```

Comment: welcome to salesforce.stackexchange user8126 (Have you consider setting a personal username ? ). The more detailed your question is, the better we can help you. Only posting some code is not the same as asking a question and telling us what you've already tried or understand.  Help us help you.

Comment: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object 
Class.testemail.<init>: line 9, column 1
 this is the error im getting again when i tried to preview of page

Answer (score 3):

Your `apex:commandButton` should probably be:

```
<apex:commandButton value="SendEmail" action="{!sendemail}"/>
```

Comment: hi I goit again a exception im pasting it right here please check itSystem.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object 
Class.testemail.<init>: line 9, column 1

Comment: @user8126 You need to initialise your list on line 2 `... contactids = new List<Id>();`. Object references start out null and you can't invoke a method on a null object reference.

Comment: still getting error of System.ListException: List index out of bounds: 20

Comment: @user8126 Your value 250 is an upper limit and the query may return less values so replace 250 in the for loop with con.size(). This isn't an interactive debugging site so I'm going to stop commenting anymore here - good luck.

Comment: sorry i did not get you